# Silverstripe throws Error 500 when exporting CSV file

Tags: php, silverstripe

I encountered HTTP error 500 on my Silverstripe website while trying to export CSV file in one of my ModelAdmin tabs. However, I noticed that if I filter the displayed results the error doesn't show up. FYI, unfiltered results have around 8000 rows of data.

Is there a specific setting on my server I could adjust to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the error? Look in your server error log. My guess based on it working when filtering is that PHP is running out of memory.

Comment: @fubar, yes it's a memory issue. I talked with someone and the recommendation was just to upgrade server.

Comment: Depending on the resources available, you may be able to just allocate more memory to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the available RAM in a number of places:

**1**. php.ini... Stored in a place like /etc/php/5.6/php.ini (not the exact location, and it all depends on your system). Use:

`php_value memory_limit 512M`

... and then restart APACHE (sudo service apache2 restart)

**2**. in your htaccess file:

`php_value memory_limit 512M`

**3**. in your mysite/_config.php file: 
`ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

**4**. using Silverstripe API (see framework/core/Core.php in SS3) - add to mysite/_config.php or another place that will run before the export takes places:

`increase_memory_limit_to('512M');`

If you replace 512M with -1 you will end up with unlimited memory.

The problem is that often you can not edit the php.ini and setting it using method 2,3 or 4 has no effect or fails for some other reason.  Best to check if it actually works by temporarily adding the following to your mysite/_config.php file:

`die('current memory limit is: '.ini_get('memory_limit'));`

Hope that helps ...